# Rails - user signin to application render a different layout but when signout rails show an error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authentication

When a user signs in to my application, I render a different layout, for example before sign in i use `application.html.erb` and when the user logs in, I change the layout to `layout2.html.erb` in the `UsersController` I call `layout 'layout2'`, this layout has many other scripts and 
stylesheets, but when the user logs out, the application shows an error saying :

```
Routing Error 

No route matches [GET] "/signout"
```

But... I checked and a `/signout` route exist, and when I do not change the layout, 
this behaves normally, the user signs in and signs out normally.

Comment: Please post your routes.rb as well as the lines in which the error happens

Comment: Maybe you could provide more information how your application gets to the faulty "/signout" request. Also please remove the irrelevant information from the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem could be with rendering link to your sign_out path, it seems that this link is correct in your layout `application.html.erb` but in `layout2.html.erb` you are rendering the link wrongly.

My guess is that your sign_out action uses a `destroy` or `post` method while you are rendering it with a get method, so it gives you the error.

Comment: Often these are HTTP DELETE's.  = link_to "Sign out", destroy_user_session_path, :method => :delete